# memoir package chapter style definition

Tags: memoir

I defined a chapter style for memoir as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt]
{memoir}

\let\STARTCODE\relax 
\let\STOPCODE\relax 

\STARTCODE
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{nicered}{rgb}{.647,.129,.149}
\makechapterstyle{mym}{

    \renewcommand\chapnamefont{\normalfont\Large\scshape\raggedleft\so}
    \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries\scshape \color{nicered}}
    \renewcommand\printchapternonum{}
    \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{\chaptitlefont ##1}
    \renewcommand\afterchaptertitle{\par\nobreak\bigskip\hrule\vskip0.5in}
}
\STOPCODE

\setlength\afterchapskip {\onelineskip }
\setlength\beforechapskip {\onelineskip }
\usepackage{lipsum}

\chapterstyle{mym}

\begin{document}

   \chapter{Chapter 1}
   \lipsum

\end{document}
```

when I run this through latex I get an error message

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\chapnamefont ... \Large \scshape \raggedleft \so 

l.33 \chapter{Chapter 1}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed.
```

but thereaftere everything works as intended.
I tried to figure out what's wrong by reading memman.pdf, but it is intimidating.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Apart from an error due to the misplaced `\afterchapskip` in `\afterchaptertitle`, I have no problem with `\chapter`. Can you make a complete example showing the issue?

Comment: What is `\so` supposed to do?

Comment: `\so` is defined neither by the LaTeX kernel nor by `memoir`.

Comment: @egreg: I edited it to be a complete example. The error message is from the log file. In the console it flags \chapter as the undefined control sequence.

Comment: No it is saying that `\so` is undefined. The *last* command on that line, it complains of. `The control sequence at the end of the top line...`

Comment: Yes, thanks! I copied this from some other chapter style without much thinking. I'll certainly accept your answers, if you state them as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macro `\so` is defined by `soul`; but there's a better method for obtaining the “letter space” effect, with `microtype`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{nicered}{rgb}{.647,.129,.149}
\makechapterstyle{mym}{%
  \renewcommand\chapnamefont{\normalfont\Large\scshape\raggedleft\lsstyle}%
  \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\Huge\scshape\color{nicered}\lsstyle}%
  \renewcommand\printchapternonum{}%
  \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{\chaptitlefont ##1}%
  \renewcommand\afterchaptertitle{\par\nobreak\bigskip\hrule\vspace{0.5in}}
}

\setlength\afterchapskip{\onelineskip}
\setlength\beforechapskip{\onelineskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\chapterstyle{mym}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

I've fixed some other glitches in the code. The main correction is removing `\bfseries`. Only a few fonts have boldface small caps, but in any case this would be too much: you already have `\Huge` and color.

[image]

Comment: Hi Enrico. How are you doing? No unsung hero badge sorry. :)